# JS cut text after few words

Tags: javascript

I am using clamps.js but all my tries were wrong, so I tried to run it with the unofficial way (different script to run).
This is a script that I am using actually

```
var item = $(".cms_clamp_text");
$clamp(item[0], {
  clamp: 2
});
```

What i want to do is to cut line after some text and write `...` at the end like demo here https://codepen.io/sair/pen/KpbeKp

The problem is that it works only for the first item and I don't know what to do.

Comment: var item = $(".cms_clamp_text");
$clamp(item, {
  clamp: 2
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [JQuery each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) for all elements

```
var item = $(".cms_clamp_text");
item.each(function(){
  $clamp(this, {
    clamp: 2
  });
});
```